# Possible chassis damage

Tags: repair, chassis, accident

I have had an accident where my Toyota Camry 2004 slipped from a curvy road into a ditch. There was no frontal collision or at least no something that I noticed but the car did have a good slide on its side while damaging the doors, mirror, side marker light, etc.. Eventually however, the car does look really bad but everything seem to be functioning.

This is a fairly old car and I am not sure whether that makes sense to fix it at all considering the costs. What I am most concerned of however is the possible chassis damage. What are the chances that it was damaged to the point that I should just get the car written off?

Comment: This question is fraught with opinion. You should just take it to the body shop and find out what the damage is, then figure it out for yourself. We cannot tell you what is beyond your means. Only you can.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 You're probably right, just want to hear other people opinions. I am definitely not a pro in this area and not sure how common chassis damage is and how likely it is to happen. Thanks.

Comment: Take it to a professional, there's no way we can make that call even if you provided pictures.

Answer (score 2):

An autobody shop can make the critical measurements to specific suspension alignment points on the unibody, according to the OEM specification.  The vehicle is "benched", usually on the pinch welds under the rockers, and then a pantograph and pointer system with accurate scales is used to measure cross-corner suspension mounting points and other critical reference dimensions.

Somewhat easier would be to get a four wheel alignment, and see how far out these numbers are, and whether they can eaily be brought back into spec.

As long as the vehicle is safe and not terribly mis-aligned as to cause severe tire wear, there's no reason not to continue driving the vehicle, other than the aesthetic.